# Nested ajax with nested rendered attribute in JSF

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

```
<h:form action="" prependId="false">
    <h:selectOneRadio value="#{managedBean.color}" id="color">
        <f:selectItem itemValue="red" itemLabel="Color1 - Red" />
        <f:selectItem itemValue="green" itemLabel="Color1 - Green" />
        <f:ajax event="click"  render="group1"  listener="#{managedBean.renderSubQuestions}"/>
    </h:selectOneRadio>         
    <h:panelGroup id="group1">
        <h:outputLabel value="  Color Description "   rendered="#{managedBean.colorRender}"></h:outputLabel>    
        <h:inputText  rendered="#{managedBean.colorRender}"></h:inputText>          
        <h:selectOneRadio id="number" value="#{managedBean.integer}"  rendered="#{managedBean.colorRender}" >
            <f:selectItem itemValue="1" itemLabel="Number1 - 1" />
            <f:selectItem itemValue="2" itemLabel="Number1 - 2" />
            <f:selectItem itemValue="3" itemLabel="Number1 - 3" />
            <f:ajax event="click"  render="group2 "  listener="#{managedBean.renderSubQuestions}"/>
        </h:selectOneRadio>         
    </h:panelGroup>
    <h:panelGroup id="group2">
        <h:outputLabel value="Number Description " rendered="#{managedBean.integerRender}"></h:outputLabel> 
        <h:inputText   rendered="#{managedBean.integerRender}"></h:inputText>
    </h:panelGroup>
</h:form>
```

In my scenario I used nested JSF AJAX with nested rendered attribute. If I select a color based on the selection, it rendered some radio button (addition elements) with AJAX. It is working fine, but additional elements with AJAX behavior is not working for me. If I remove `rendered` attribute in number radio button, it is working fine. I dont know where I did mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is most likely what your `ManagedBean` is not in `ViewScoped` or `SessionScoped`. When you post back to the bean, you are loosing `rendered` states. I suggest to change for the `ViewScoped` one.

**Not related :**

- You should remove the `action` attribute from the `h:form` since JSF override it.